# Richfaces extendeddatatable sorting problem

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am developing a web app using JSF, RichFaces, EJB3, Hibernate and Seam.

I have an extended data table and showing a list (say userList) which has multi columns in it. Moreover, because of that this datatable is selectable, I want to keep the selected row indexes even if the sorting is changed by the user.

In other words of what I mean is that when the sorting of columns is changed, the order of row indexes is changed as well. Therefore, I want to invoke an action when the user clicks on sorting on each time. I tried many ways, but could nt find a solution to achieve it yet.

Do you have any idea about which listener or method is being called when sorting is clicked by the user in rich extendeddatatable? I cant understand what the point is in that...

Any help would be appreciated.
Many Thanks,
Baris

Comment: I notice this question is almost 2 years old. Did you figure it out, @Bariscan ? If yes, can you post your answer here?

Comment: I really do not remember so sorry:( but I would take this oppurtunity to suggest primefaces rather than richfaces due to its better convenience, flexibility and ease.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't help those of use locked into RichFaces by preexisting company strategy. :)

Answer (score 0):

A code sample would have been nice, but it sounds like you have a separate list that contains the selected indices, and only update that list on a selection event.

Have you considered having the selection state live with the data object via a bean:

```
public DataBean {
  private DataModel model;
  private boolean selected;

  //standard getters and setters omitted
}
```

JSF code:

```
<h:column>
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="dataBean.selected">
    <a4j:support event="onclick" ajaxsingle="true" />
  </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
</h:column>
```

Tie your selection state to the model like this and sorting won't be an issue at all.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply at first. Even if your approach is a good one, it is not directly related about my problem indeed. I would just like to know how I can invoke an action when user clicks the little sorting arrow which is placed at the top of each columns individually.

    
     <rich:column sortable="true" sortBy="#{cap.userId}" 
    filterBy="#{cap.userId}" filterEvent="onkeyup" width="170px" id="col1"
    label="User ID">
    <f:facet name="header">
     <h:outputText value="User ID" id="out1"/>  
  </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{cap.userId}" id="out2"/></rich:column>

Comment: The problem you stated was that you were losing the selection state of your rows after sorting...

Comment: The extended data table does not require using a selectbooleancheckbox in order to keep selection state. That's why I dont prefer to use a checkbox in my case it is waste while extended tabel enables user to select a row by just clicking the row itself.
So the actual problem in here is, I am synchronizing extendedtable with my list got from backing bean. I can get the selected row key. But when sorting is changed, it is not match the row key with my result list.
As a result, if i can execute an action when user clicks sorting arrow, everything will be ok.How can i execute an action as sorting?